# Reset Javascript Timer for Image Slider

Tags: javascript, timer, slider

I am creating an image slider and using a JavaScript timer to advance to the next picture.  When the user clicks on the forward or back button (see picture below) the time the slide is displayed decreases greatly.  I need help making the buttons advance the slide and reset the timer and the same time. I am attaching my JavaScript, HTML, and CSS to cover my code thoroughly.

My JavaScript:

```
var imageShown = 1;
var total = 7;

function autoplay() {
    var image = document.getElementById('picture');
    imageShown = imageShown + 1;
    if(imageShown > total){imageShown = 1;}
    if(imageShown < 1){imageShown = total;} 
    picture.src = "Images/img"+ imageShown +".jpg";
    console.log("Pic Changed");
}

window.setInterval(autoplay, 5000);

function pic(x) {
    var image = document.getElementById('picture');
    imageShown = imageShown + x;
    if(imageShown > total){imageShown = 1;}
    if(imageShown < 1){imageShown = total;} 
    picture.src = "Images/img"+ imageShown +".jpg";
    console.log("Button clicked");
    window.clearInterval(autoplay);
    window.setInterval(autoplay, 5000);
}
```

My HTML:

```
<img src="Images/img1.jpg" id="picture" >
<div class="left_div"><img onClick="pic(-1)" class="left_click" src="Images/left.png"></div>
<div class="right_div"><img onClick="pic(+1)" class="right_click" src="Images/right.png"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
    margin:0px;
    }
#imageslider {
    height:700px;
    width:1000px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:4px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-right: 5000px;
    padding-top: 1000px;
    }
#picture {
    height:750px;
    width:1000px;
    position:relative;
    padding-top: 50px
    }
.left_div {
    height: 750px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 0px;
}
.right_div {
    height: 750px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    right: 0px;
}
.left_click {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:20px;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
.right_click {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    right:20px;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
.left_div:hover .left_click {
    opacity:0.6;
    }
.right_div:hover .right_click {
    opacity:0.6;
}
.left:hover .left1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use clearInterval as following:

```
clearInterval(autoplay);
```

or as

```
window.clearInterval(autoplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might be trying to reset the interval incorrectly

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp this gives an example of how to reset a function set to an interval in javascript

Comment: You are trying to clear the function not a variable try this var myVar = setInterval(autoplay() }, 5000); then clearInterval(myVar) then set the interval again