# Setting loop on a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set a loop on a slider but it would always stop on the last slider. Please help.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/na8zvhwh/3/)

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('div#slideshow .active');
    var $next = $active.next();    

    $next.addClass('active');

    $active.removeClass('active');
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

Comment: On the fiddle the pics do not show up. can you update the code so there are pics to see for the slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to set `$next` to the first image when you reach the end. You can assume that if there is no `$next` elements, then it means that you need to start over from the beginning.

For example like this:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('div#slideshow .active');
    var $next = $active.next();
    if (!$next.length) {
        $next = $('div#slideshow > :first');
    }
    $next.addClass('active');
    $active.removeClass('active');
}

$(function () {
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 1000);
});
```

Unrelated, but instead of `setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);` pass function reference like in example above.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/na8zvhwh/2/

Answer (score 0):

I would say that .next() make things needlessly complicated. This task is easily solved with some jQuery and a little math. Complete solution at the bottom, step-by-step with explanations following.

Pretty much only the internals of `slideSwitch` are changed. Requires that `.active` is set on one element. I like this solution because of its mathematical elegance, and because it's pretty easy to use once you understand the concept of it, and because it allows us to understand what we do instead of relying on things that "just work".

**Step-by-step with explanation**

What you want to do is get a list, iterate over it, change the class and then start from the beginning, right? A trick for this is using `index % length`.

Pretty much only the internals of `slideSwitch` are changed. Requires that `.active` is set on one element.

First, get the list of slides: (cache outside function for better performance)

```
var $list = $("div#slideshow");
```

Then, we want to find the active element and its index. This is done with:

```
var $current = $list.find(".active").index();
```

Then the magic. To find the next number, regardless of current position, we take `$current`, and add 1, then get the modulus (remained, essentially) of that number divided by the number of items total. The list of elements in `#slideshow` is returned by `$list.children()`.

Thus, it will magically wrap around and start over when it reaches the end.

```
var $next = ($current + 1) % $list.children().length;
```

Then it's only a matter of removing the class from the current element and adding it to the next, using `.get(index)` which allows us to `find()` elements by their index and wrapping them in a jQuery object so we can use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`, because backwards compability.

```
$($list.children().get($current)).removeClass("active")
$($list.children().get($next)).addClass("active");
```

And that's it.

**Full solution:**

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thn1vnmg/

```
function slideSwitch() 
{
    // Cache this outside function for performance
    var $list = $("div#slideshow"),
        $current = $list.find(".active").index(),
        $next = ($current+1) % $list.children().length;

    $($list.children().get($current)).removeClass("active")
    $($list.children().get($next)).addClass("active");
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( slideSwitch, 1000 );
});
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a great alternative

Answer (score 0):

A simple script that I use is this.

```
var imageShown = 1;
var total = 7;

function pic() {
var image = document.getElementById('picture');
imageShown = imageShown + x;
if(imageShown > total){imageShown = 1;}
if(imageShown < 1){imageShown = total;} 
picture.src = "Images/img"+ imageShown +".jpg";
}
window.setInterval(pic, 5000);
```

You will need to customize the variables as needed to make your script match.  Before this will work the pictures need to be put in the sub folder Images with the name img1, img2, and so forth.  I know this will work because I have created an image slider that runs through automatically.  [Reset Javascript Timer for Image Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864879/reset-javascript-timer-for-image-slider)